# 2 mysql instances in MAC

Tags: python, mysql, django, macos, xampp

i recently switched to mac. first and foremost i installed xampp.
then for django-python-mysql connectivity, i "somehow" ended up installing a seperate MySQL.
now the seperate mysql installation is active all the time and the Xampp one doesnt switch on unless i kill the other one.

what i wanted to know is it possible to make xampp work with the seperate mysql installation? because that way i wouldnt have to tinker around with the mysqlDB adapter for python?

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the listening port of one of the installations and they shouldn't conflict anymore with each other.

**Update:** You need to find the mysql configuration file `my.cnf` of the server which should get a new port (the one from xampp should be somewhere in the xampp folder). Find the line `port=3306` in the `[mysqld]` section. You could change it to something like `3307`.

You will also need to specify the new port when connecting to the server from your applications.

Comment: can u tell me how to do that?